# How to install SSL / TLS certificate CA file in Mac for secure (HTTPS) remote repository docker login

Tags: macos, docker, ssl, openshift, docker-registry

I have set-up or have been provided with an secured URL (HTTPS) to a remote Docker registry. I need to perform docker login into the remote registry in order to be able to push my locally built Docker images.

The command would be something like:

```
docker login -u myUser https://registry.mydomain.example.com
```

However, docker login fails with x509 certificate verification error like:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry.mydomain.example.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

**I'm using macOS / OS X, how can I get my local Docker (Docker client) to accept remote repository's TLS certificate for HTTPS traffic?**

Also, once the secure HTTPS connection works, how do I build and push my image to the remote repository, after I've written the Dockerfile and tested locally that my image works?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the Docker documentation's link regarding this matter specifically mentions, the Linux/Unix instructions work for macOS / OS X as well:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/

I got below instructions working with MacBook Pro using macOs High Sierra 10.13.5 (17F77)
Docker client (local Docker) version: 18.03.1-ce

Place the Certificate Authority (CA) file, provided by the remote registry admin, into the specific folder structure via terminal commands:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.mydomain.example.com
sudo cp ca.crt /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.mydomain.example.com
```

**Note:** If you are using URL with port to connect to the registry, the port needs to be included in the foldername under certs.d folder. The URL can also be in the form of IP:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/registry.mydomain.example.com:443
sudo mkdir -p /etc/docker/certs.d/172.123.123.1:443
```

**EDIT TO ADD!**
I tested this with a co-worker and it was discovered that addition of the CA file into macOS Keychain was required (I had also done this previously). `It is currently unknown if the above /etc/docker steps are even required on Mac.` We used this guide to import ca.crt file into the Keychain (visible as "not trusted" at Certificates menu).
https://www.sslsupportdesk.com/how-to-import-a-certificate-into-mac-os/

Afterwards, restart your local Docker.

Docker login should work normally afterwards. If you still keep getting the x509 unknown authority error, it might be a good idea to verify the remote registry's server certificate's (obtainable e.g. by navigating to the registry's URL with browser) validity against the CA file, using openssl commands:
https://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html

Below is an example if working with OpenShift integrated (Atomic) registry:

```
oc login https://registry.mydomain.example.com -u myUser --certificate-authority=ca.crt
docker login -u $(oc whoami) -p $(oc whoami -t) https://registry.mydomain.example.com
```

You should get a prompt that `Login Succeeded`, then:

```
docker build -t registry.mydomain.example.com/openshiftProject/my-image:1.0 .
docker push registry.mydomain.example.com/openshiftProject/my-image:1.0
```

Comment: I can confirm that just adding the CA cert to the keychain and trusting it was all that was needed. You don't need to add it to `/etc/docker/certs.d`.